# How to store a large number of fields in db - individual columns vs xml column

Tags: json, xml, sql-server-2008, large-data

I have a requirement to store a medical form in the database which contains 500 data elements

I could

1. create a table with that many columns
2. create one `xml` column that contains the entire data set
3. create one `varchar(max)` column that contains the entire data set in `json` format.

I guess (1) is easier to search and read data back (no conversion), (2) is easier to scale and encrypt etc and (3) is less footprint that (2). The forms can possibly change in future too.

I would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: (3) might *seem* to have less overhead - but the `XML` datatype in SQL Server is stored in a tokenized and optimized fashion (it's **not** stored just as a text blob!), and the XQuery support can be used against XML columns to fetch individual bits from it. No such support for Json (yet) in SQL Server ...

Comment: yes, i'm aware of the better support for XML in SQL. I mainly want to know opting for individual columns is not the way to go. I'm also interested in hearing from people who have had experience with this type of situation. This must be a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store different medical forms that do have different structure go with XML. If data structure is always same do the columns, unless you will never read or edit the data inside the form.